# How to stop the Document backup to icloud in before ios 5.0

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, nsdocumentdirectory

I am doing one application.In that i am creating the .txt files in DocumentDirectory at runtime.But they will backup to icloud.SO now i want to stop the backup in before ios 5 versions.From ios 5 onwards we have option to stop the back up process.I want to store the files in documents and not back up in before 5.0 versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed ios version prior then ios5 then no data will backup to cloud. Becouse i-cloud comes with ios5.

In ios5.0 you can stop your backup with following function

```
(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL {
    NSLog(@"in add skipBackUpAtrribute method.......");
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}
```

Comment: as per apple guidelince put all your meta data into Library/Cache/..
because it will not backup to iCloud. Don't put your data into Document folder.
get Ios version, if it is ios5 family then put do not backup flag and if higher then leave it. But make sure you put your data into Library/Cache/..